# How to automatically generate new 'lists' with jQuery drag-and-drop when used ones have at least one element in them

Tags: jquery, list, user-interface, drag-and-drop

Hi so I'm working with jQuery right now, still very new to it, and I'm trying to drag-and-drop elements from one already created and visible list to another, sort of like Solitaire, where the original list is the deck of cards and the spots are the holders for the individual suits. My question is, is there a way to automatically generate new lists whenever one is in use? For example in Solitaire, let's say I've already put at least one card into each holder. The user interface would then know to create a new category next to the last used one. I hope this makes sense!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research. I think I'm going to go with the jQuery Droppable plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Droppable . It should be good for you too.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually going to be using Sortable (which uses Draggable) so that the images can be moved around and are not stuck in a position.

Comment: You're totally right, sortable is the way to go. Check this demo out http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists